# How to automate third-party UI control

Tags: windows, mfc, ui-automation

I'm trying to extracting data from third-party software. The window has a customised tab control (not the standard one) which contains multi SysTreeView32 in tabs.

The software has different versions and each version has different set of tabs.

Both Inspect.exe and Spy++ only show the control itself without any information about the tab children.

Do you know how to programmatically select the specific tab by its title?

Here's the information of the 3rd-party control from Inspect.exe

```
How found:                            Mouse move (292,346)
                                      hwnd=0x005203F6 32bit class="Afx:5080000:0:10003:0:0" style=0x56000000 ex=0x0
Name:                                 ""
ControlType:                          UIA_PaneControlTypeId (0xC371)
LocalizedControlType:                 "窗格"
BoundingRectangle:                    {l:98 t:327 r:410 b:1014}
IsEnabled:                            true
IsOffscreen:                          false
IsKeyboardFocusable:                  true
HasKeyboardFocus:                     false
AccessKey:                            ""
ProcessId:                            36076
RuntimeId:                            [2A.5203F6]
AutomationId:                         "221"
FrameworkId:                          "Win32"
ClassName:                            "Afx:5080000:0:10003:0:0"
NativeWindowHandle:                   0x5203F6
ProviderDescription:                  "[pid:41692,hwnd:0x5203F6 Main:Nested [pid:36076,hwnd:0x5203F6 Annotation(parent link):Microsoft: Annotation Proxy (unmanaged:uiautomationcore.dll); Main:Microsoft: MSAA Proxy (unmanaged:uiautomationcore.dll)]; Hwnd(parent link):Microsoft: HWND Proxy (unmanaged:uiautomationcore.dll)]"
IsPassword:                           false
HelpText:                             ""
LegacyIAccessible.ChildId:            0
LegacyIAccessible.DefaultAction:      ""
LegacyIAccessible.Description:        ""
LegacyIAccessible.Help:               ""
LegacyIAccessible.KeyboardShortcut:   ""
LegacyIAccessible.Name:               ""
LegacyIAccessible.Role:               客户端 (0xA)
LegacyIAccessible.State:              可设定焦点 (0x100000)
LegacyIAccessible.Value:              ""
IsAnnotationPatternAvailable:         false
IsDragPatternAvailable:               false
IsDockPatternAvailable:               false
IsDropTargetPatternAvailable:         false
IsExpandCollapsePatternAvailable:     false
IsGridItemPatternAvailable:           false
IsGridPatternAvailable:               false
IsInvokePatternAvailable:             false
IsItemContainerPatternAvailable:      false
IsLegacyIAccessiblePatternAvailable:  true
IsMultipleViewPatternAvailable:       false
IsObjectModelPatternAvailable:        false
IsRangeValuePatternAvailable:         false
IsScrollItemPatternAvailable:         false
IsScrollPatternAvailable:             false
IsSelectionItemPatternAvailable:      false
IsSelectionPatternAvailable:          false
IsSpreadsheetItemPatternAvailable:    false
IsSpreadsheetPatternAvailable:        false
IsStylesPatternAvailable:             false
IsSynchronizedInputPatternAvailable:  false
IsTableItemPatternAvailable:          false
IsTablePatternAvailable:              false
IsTextChildPatternAvailable:          false
IsTextEditPatternAvailable:           false
IsTextPatternAvailable:               false
IsTextPattern2Available:              false
IsTogglePatternAvailable:             false
IsTransformPatternAvailable:          false
IsTransform2PatternAvailable:         false
IsValuePatternAvailable:              false
IsVirtualizedItemPatternAvailable:    false
IsWindowPatternAvailable:             false
FirstChild:                           "" 树
LastChild:                            "" 树
Next:                                 [null]
Previous:                             [null]
Other Props:                          Object has no additional properties
Children:                             "" 树
Ancestors:                            "" 窗格
                                      "" 窗格
                                      "" 窗格
                                      "V6" 对话框
                                      "" 窗格
                                      "" 窗格
                                      "" 容器
                                      "V9.32" 窗口
                                      "桌面" 窗格
                                      [ No Parent ]
```

Comment: *"Both Inspect.exe and Spy++ only show the control itself without any information about the tab children."* - In that case there's nothing you can do. You'll have to ask the control vendor to implement the automation interfaces.

Comment: It is not possible to ask the 3rd-party to implement automation at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

If "AutomationId" is unique, can we try to map the logical names with the "AutomationId" & use those fields in automation. I may be wrong, but a possible solution.